# JS data transformation methods don't seem to be working

Tags: javascript, arrays

Create a function 'calcAverageHumanAge', which accepts an arrays of dog's
ages ('ages'), and does the following things in order:

1. Calculate the dog age in human years using the following formula: if the dog is
   <= 2 years old, humanAge = 2 * dogAge. If the dog is > 2 years old,
   humanAge = 16 + dogAge * 4
2. Exclude all dogs that are less than 18 human years old (which is the same as
   keeping dogs that are at least 18 years old)
3. Calculate the average human age of all adult dogs (you should already know
   from other challenges how we calculate averages )
4. Run the function for both test datasets

Test data:

Data 1: [5, 2, 4, 1, 15, 8, 3]
Data 2: [16, 6, 10, 5, 6, 1, 4]

My solution(idk why wont work):

```
const calcAverageHumanAge = function (ageList) {
const avgAge = ageList
.map(val => (val <= 2 ? 2 * val : 16 + val * 4))
.fliter(val => val >= 18)
.reduce((acc, val, i, list) => {
  return acc + val / list.length;
}, 0);};
```

Comment: Your last `reduce` doesn't return anything.

Comment: sorry typing error, I had return in original code though

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: ageList.map(...).fliter is not a function" is the error

Comment: `fliter` => `filter`

Comment:  dumb me . Thanks ✌️

Answer (score 2):

You have three issues. Your `reduce` doesn't return anything is the main problem, but you're also dividing by `list.length` in each callback which doesn't make any sense (actually it does and I'm dumb), and then you aren't returning anything from the function. You want something like this:

```
const calcAverageHumanAge = function (ageList) {
    const filteredVals = ageList
        .map(val => (val <= 2 ? 2 * val : 16 + val * 4))
        .filter(val => val >= 18);
    return filteredVals.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val) / filteredVals.length;
};
```

When run on your data:

```
calcAverageHumanAge([5, 2, 4, 1, 15, 8, 3]); // 44 
calcAverageHumanAge([16, 6, 10, 5, 6, 1, 4]); // 47.333
```

Comment: Bro your right ,But if you try running my code it works just fine. calcAverageHumanAge is updating each time reduce method adds a value in accumulator and then divides it by list length . Thanks though ✌️

Comment: You're right. I was thinking you were doing `return (acc + val)/list.length`. Your way was fine there.